# Binary Tree iterate in C#

Tags: c#, tree, binary-tree

I want to generate a binary tree using C# and insert a node in it.

I have tried a many way but it did not generate any binary tree.
I want to Write a function that will iterate through the tree from the root to the leaves so how can i achieve this.

Binary tree is my class in following code.

Find my following code.

```
        int[] values = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree(values);

        var node1 = new Node();
        var node2 = new Node();
        var node3 = new Node();
        var node4 = new Node();
        var node5 = new Node();
        node1.Value = 1;
        node2.Value = 2;
        node3.Value = 3;
        node4.Value = 4;
        node5.Value = 5;
        node1.Left = node2;
        node1.Right = node3;
        node2.Left = node4;
        node2.Right = node5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [ngenerics](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/) library. It contains a good implementation of [binary tree](http://code.google.com/p/ngenerics/wiki/BinaryTree) with recursive tree traversal.